# Know Which compiler is used in visual studio 2015?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

i have visual studio 2015 and .net framework 4.5

i found that roslyn compiler is lunch with visual studio 2015(as default compiler ) but i dnt knw that i am using roslyn compilet or not.

i want to know that how can i know which compiler i am using by command ?

i found this code

```
Console.Write(typeof(string).Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion);
```

but this not showing right thing i want name of compiler.

this is showing about roslyn compiler but does not show any command that show compiler name.

[How to use roslyn c# compiler with visual studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138235/how-to-use-roslyn-c-sharp-compiler-with-visual-studio-2015)

**Note: i am new in this thing**

Comment: If it's a one-time check, use one of the C# 6 features, e.g. string interpolation. This code will only compile with roslyn: string foo="123";string bar=$"foo={foo}";

Comment: i can do auto property initialization that is c# 6.0 features  but i cant not show roslyn syntax visualizer in view->other windows why? any idea ? should i install code analysis package from nuget " Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis -Version 1.1.1 " ???

Comment: I think that requires a specific plugin/extension, I think '.NET Compiler Platform SDK'. See Tools -> Extensions and Updates.

Comment: On .NET Framework 4.6 and above with Visual Studio 2015, you must be using Roslyn based compiler. Don't know what you are asking exactly. Note that **you cannot be using .NET Framework 4.5 if you have installed Visual Studio 2015**.

Comment: @Evert i installed that but nothing is shown that i want to found "roslyn visualizer"

Comment: @LexLi thanks for your sugestion :)

Comment: @LexLi did you know how to i start make project based on asp .net VNext technology ?

Comment: It is called 'syntax visualizer'

Comment: no roslyn name is not there @Evert

Comment: @ShahNiral based on this question, I don't recommend you try ASP.NET Core 1.0 out. You don't have enough experience to jump to that wild horse at this moment. But well, https://docs.asp.net contains what you might read (not up-to-date yet).